# OnClick returning "Button Title"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a function that returns a "Button Title" at an OnClick event? e.g. Clicking on a Cancel button would return "Cancel"?

Comment: could you put up some code for us to help you? A button title? what do you mean, the name of the button? if that is so it's quite simple but please add some HTML at least.

Comment: You mean `title="Cancel"` in input, or `type="cancel"` or what exactly?

Comment: @bitoiu The problem is i cant write any code because i didnt found the function yet :( com'on man please, it's just a small function and i'll do the rest.

Comment: @debute i needed only to get the "title".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript

```
document.getelementbyname("ID").Text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.button").click( function(){ // trigger click event
    var caption = $(this).text(); // retrieve the text value of this element
    alert( caption );

    return false;
}
```

Presuming you have HTML like:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

Function to get text explanation: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Function to handle click event explanation: http://api.jquery.com/click/